# Select Option: Display Selected Value On Change using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to display data from html file on select using Ajax. 
I having a list of football league . When selected, i want the data from `league.html` display this inside `#league-display`.

And also i want the value of the first option display by default inside `#league-display`. Please Help..

```
<select name="league">
<option value="premiere-league">Premiere League</option>
<option value="champions-league">Champions League</option>
<option value="laliga">La Liga</option>
<option value="bundesliga">Bundesliga</option>
</select>
<div id="league-display"></div>
```

Here is the `league.html` content

```
<div id="league-details">
 <div id="premiere-league">
   Data of Premiere League
 </div>
 <div id="champions-league">
   Data of Champions League
 </div>
 <div id="laliga">
   Data of La Liga
 </div>
 <div id="bundesliga">
   Data of Bundesliga League
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want div data to be displayed as option?

Comment: i want it to display the div data inside #league-display when select

Answer (score 1):

Write a `change` event for your `select` and use **[`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** to load specific location of your `html` page. Consider below example

```
<select name="league">
     <option value="premiere-league">Premiere League</option>
     <option value="champions-league">Champions League</option>
     <option value="laliga">La Liga</option>
     <option value="bundesliga">Bundesliga</option>
</select>
<div id="league-display"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('select[name="league"]').on('change',function(){
  var url="league.html#"+this.value; //construct url and fetch only part of page
  $("#league-display").load(url,function(){
      //Anything you want do after contents are loaded
  });
})
```

On page load if you want to display the current selected data then again make use of same `load` functionality. To be a better one, you can just move your loading thing inside a `function` and call the function accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   loadData(); //call the function
});

$('select[name="league"]').on('change',loadData); //assign the function to the change event

function loadData(){
    var url=$('select[name="league"] option:selected').val();
    $("#league-display").load(url,function(){
       //Anything you want do after contents are loaded
    });
}
```